# rvm doesn't revert back to system ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'll let the shell log explain itself:

```
root:~# rvm current
system
root:~# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
root:~# rvm use 1.9.2
Using /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
root:~# rvm current
ruby-1.9.2-p290
root:~# which ruby
/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
root:~# rvm system
root:~# rvm current
system
root:~# which ruby
/root/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
root:~#
```

At this point, if rvm claims that the current installation is "system", shouldn't ruby point back to /usr/bin/ruby?

Moreover, can someone explain, at a high level, what happens when one executes "rvm [version]", where [version] could be "system"? I understand that it's messing with the paths of where the current "ruby", "gem", etc point to, but is it doing some other stuff under the covers?

Comment: is it the same after `rvm get head && rvm reload` ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to older version of rvm which was not issuing warning when `use` was broken, new versions of RVM will tell you that you can not use ruby because RVM is not loaded as function.

Other point might be that system rubt and default ruby might be conflicting, and even you get it working - it still will point to rvm default ruby instead of system.

And last - you have installed user mode rvm for root, this is the least tested use case of RVM, actually It's even hard to get it, it might be the cause of the problem.